# Jenkins: Base64 Encode JSON

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

New to Jenkins and trying to base64 encode this:

```
stages {
        stage('Debug') {
            steps {
                script {
                  outgoing_json = '''{
                      "spec": "1.0.0"
                  }
                  '''
                  outgoing_encoded = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo $outgoing_json | base64")
                }

                echo "outgoing_encoded: ${outgoing_encoded}"
            }
}
```

Of course, I'm getting an error because it contains double quotes. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can take return value in a variable with returnStdout as true:

```
def ret = sh(script: 'echo $outgoing_json | base64', returnStdout: true, returnStatus: true)
```

More info : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script.
Note you can also add `encoding: 'UTF-8'`to specify the encoding explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
outgoing_encoded = "echo $outgoing_json".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

Comment: This will NOT work in Jenkins, as `getBytes()` is forbidden

Comment: you have to allow getBytes() as other methods in the admin area: https://yourJenkins/scriptApproval

Comment: And this is exactly something I don't want to do :)

Comment: are there any alternative solutions?